# Laravel 5 undefined index _sf2_meta

Tags: undefined, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and everything was working fine until i made an api request to my application which return a json response.
I got the exception

> undefined index _sf2_meta

Is this because i am not logged in ?
or is there something else?

Comment: Yeah! I'm also getting same error, What to do?